# Удалить лишние пробелы между словами, оставив только по одному

Tags: java, строки

Дана строка символов. Группы символов в ней разделены   пробелами.   Удалить   лишние   пробелы между словами, оставив только по одному. (java)(NetBeans)

Comment: @Алексей1526 А 1526 -- это год рождения?

Прибьют Ваш вопрос. Не соответствует правилам

Comment: такие вещи делаются конечным автоматом. В данном случае у автомата 2 состояния (был ли предыдущий символ пробелом).

Answer (score 11):

Зачем усложнять?

```
System.out.println("Твой      текст           тут".replaceAll("[\\s]{2,}", " "));
```

Comment: А квадратные скобки вроде лишние?

Comment: Вместо `"[\\s]{2,}"` можно использовать `"\\s+"`.

Answer (score 1):

Без регулярных выражений будет так:

```
final String twoSpaces="  ";
final String oneSpace=" ";
String myText; //наша строка
while(myText.indexOf(twoSpaces) >= 0) {
   myText.replace(twoSpaces, oneSpace);
}
```

С regexp'ами которые я лично не люблю - народ допишет.

P.S. Добрый я сегодня.

Answer (score 1):

Можно регулярным выражением, вот например

```
private static final Pattern CLEAR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\\s]+");
...
CLEAR_PATTERN .matcher(result).replaceAll(" ").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = "парам пам  пам   пам       пам";

while(x.contains("  ")) {
    String replace = x.replace("  ", " ");
    x=replace;

}
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?