# Пробелы между цифрами при сохранении в БД

Tags: java

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У меня есть форма, на которой есть input и в этом input я пишу число, например 45000, но когда я нажимаю сохранить, это число у меня в блоке отображается с пробелом через каждые 3 знака, примерно вот так 45 000 и когда я нажимаю на редактирование данной записи у меня в input появляется это число с пробелом и если не убрать пробел, то вылетит ошибка :

`Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Double'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3 400"`

Форма с инпутами:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 add-section">
<div>
<div>
    <form method="post" action="/tab/tabList" enctype="multipart/form- 
data" class="col-12" id="add_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Введите модель" 
class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="ENTER PRICE" 
class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter
quantity" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter 
description" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
Выберите файл <input type="file" name="file">
</span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Форма редактирования:

```
<div class="edit-form col-7">
<h3 class="display">Editor</h3>
<form action="/tab/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="name" value="${tab.model}" class="form- 
control">
<input type="text" name="price" value="${tab.price}" class="form- 
control">
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="${tab.quantity}" 
class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="description" value="${tab.description}" 
class="form-control">
<input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
<img src="/img/${tab.filename}" class="card-img-top">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${tab.id}">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form- 
control">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Класс сущности:

```
@Entity
public class Tab {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "* Заполните поле.")
private String model;

@NotNull(message = "* Заполните поле.")
private Double price;

private String filename;

@NotNull(message = "* Заполните поле.")
private Integer quantity;

@NotBlank(message = "* Заполните поле.")
private String description;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tab")
private List<TabChars> characts = new ArrayList<>();

public Tab(){}


public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public List<TabChars> getCharacts() {
return characts;
}

public void setCharacts(List<TabChars> characts) {
this.characts = characts;
}

public Long getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getModel() {
return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
this.model = model;
}

public Double getPrice() {
return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
this.price = price;
}

public String getFilename() {
return filename;
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
this.filename = filename;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я конечна не эксперт в Java, но почему не убирать пробелы после того как форма ушла? Это стандартная валидация.

[Вот здесь посмотри](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/283470/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83)

**Валидация это наше все.** Таким образом, когда вы будете проверять данные на правильность, у вас не будет возникать подобных ошибок.
Советую вам более подробнее разобраться в этой теме.